# tracker errors in opencv3

Tags: c++, opencv, tld, tracker

I want to use TLD tracker. So, I installed OpenCV contrib (master), same as [here](https://putuyuwono.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/building-and-installing-opencv-3-0-on-windows-7-64-bit/).

I installed OpenCV 3.x on VS2015. Installation process finished completely and, for tracking, it created just tracking.hpp and tracking_c.hpp in ...\include\opencv2\video location.

Also, in lib folder, I just have opencv_ts310d.lib and opencv_world310d.lib.

Now I want to run [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/52872/how-to-perform-tld-tracking-on-roi-bounding-box-using-opencv-c-builtin-methods/) tracker algorithm but this line make error:

Ptr < Tracker > tracker = Tracker::create(tracker_algorithm);

In other words, the compiler can't find tracker.

Comment: How did you link your program?

Comment: @Berriel , what is your mean exactly? i just copy software of above link and debug it same as other projects. i don't have any problem with usual softwares and i can run it, but in this software, tracker module don't work and i think it isn't installed yet.